# Changing the cursor on an ESRI map

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

We are building an app starting from the [ArcGIS Tax Parcel Viewer](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=23cc5b90b78d45e0bd51ede193328568).  I have added buttons to allow users to switch to Street View or Pictometry when they click on the map.  All that is working fine, but now I want to change to a custom cursor after pressing a button so they know when these options have been turned on.

Using CSS like this:

```css
cursor: url(../images/cursors/Pictometry.cur), default;
```

I have been able to turn on the custom cursors over pretty much every DIV in the page **except** the map.  Even when I enable it for the entire `<html>` or `<body>` tags, as soon as the cursor goes over the map, it reverts to the default look.  So far, I have been unable to locate any CSS or HTML elements that I can change to enable this (either in the code or programmatically).  Does anyone know if this can even be changed, and if so, where?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
map.setMapCursor("url(custom.cur),auto")
```

Here is the [api reference](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/map-amd.html#setmapcursor)